# How to use iAds in landscape in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, iad

Im using iOS6 SDK and currently apple deprecated landscape mode. Is there any work around to use landscape iAds because my game only runs on landscape mode.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

**Landscape** mode is not deprecated only the method

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

has been deprecated. Now you can use below methods:-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
} 
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your answer has anything to do with the question. It's about iAd and the deprecated properties. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009562-AppendixA

Comment: @Kai- read ur question first line .my ans will based on  currently apple deprecated landscape mode not in iAd..

Comment: I am aware that orientation methods are replaced with new ones. But my question was how to use iAds in landscape mode